# how to create a viewmodel with api?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-viewmodel

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

*how to create a viewModel class from the mainActivity class so that the data from the parse doesn't change when the orientation is changed or the data remains intact. The point is how to do a viewModel with api.how to create a viewmodel with api?*

```
private var listData: ArrayList<DataUsers> = ArrayList()
private lateinit var adapter: UsersAdapter

companion object {
    internal val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val textbar: TextView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    textbar.text = title
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarr)
    adapter = UsersAdapter(listData)

    recyclerViewConfig()
    searchData()
    getDataHome()
}

private fun searchData() {
    user_search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            if (query.isEmpty()) {
                return true
            } else {
                listData.clear()
                getDataSearch(query)
            }
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
}

private fun recyclerViewConfig() {
    recycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(recycleView.context)
    recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recycleView.addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(
            recycleView.context,
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
        )
    )
}

private fun getDataHome() {
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "token -----")
    client.addHeader("User-Agent", "request")
    val url = "https://api.github.com/users"
    client.get(url, object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        override fun onSuccess(
            statusCode: Int,
            headers: Array<Header>,
            responseBody: ByteArray
        ) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val result = String(responseBody)
            Log.d(TAG, result)
            try {
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(result)
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val username: String = jsonObject.getString("login")
                    getDataDetail(username)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            statusCode: Int,
            headers: Array<Header>,
            responseBody: ByteArray,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val errorMessage = when (statusCode) {
                401 -> "$statusCode : Bad Request"
                403 -> "$statusCode : Forbidden"
                404 -> "$statusCode : Not Found"
                else -> "$statusCode : ${error.message + " GIT"}"
            }
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    })
}



private fun getDataDetail(id: String) {
   progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "token -------")
    client.addHeader("User-Agent", "request")
    val url = "https://api.github.com/users/$id"
    client.get(url, object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        override fun onSuccess(
            statusCode: Int,
            headers: Array<Header>,
            responseBody: ByteArray
        ) {
           progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val result = String(responseBody)
            Log.d(TAG, result)
            try {
                val jsonObject = JSONObject(result)
                val username: String? = jsonObject.getString("login").toString()
                val name: String? = jsonObject.getString("name").toString()
                val avatar: String? = jsonObject.getString("avatar_url").toString()
                val company: String? = jsonObject.getString("company").toString()
                val location: String? = jsonObject.getString("location").toString()
                val repository: Int = jsonObject.getInt("public_repos")
                val followers: Int = jsonObject.getInt("followers")
                val following: Int = jsonObject.getInt("following")
                listData.add(
                    DataUsers(
                        username,
                        name,
                        avatar,
                        company,
                        location,
                        repository,
                        followers,
                        following
                    )
                )
                showRecyclerList()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            statusCode: Int,
            headers: Array<Header>,
            responseBody: ByteArray,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
           progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val errorMessage = when (statusCode) {
                401 -> "$statusCode : Bad Request"
                403 -> "$statusCode : Forbidden"
                404 -> "$statusCode : Not Found"
                else -> "$statusCode : ${error.message + " DETAIL"}"
            }
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    })
}

private fun getDataSearch(id: String) {
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "token ---------")
    client.addHeader("User-Agent", "request")
    val url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=$id"
    client.get(url, object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        override fun onSuccess(
            statusCode: Int,
            headers: Array<Header>,
            responseBody: ByteArray
        ) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val result = String(responseBody)
            Log.d(TAG, result)
            try {
                val jsonArray = JSONObject(result)
                val item = jsonArray.getJSONArray("items")
                for (i in 0 until item.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = item.getJSONObject(i)
                    val username: String = jsonObject.getString("login")
                    getDataDetail(username)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            statusCode: Int,
            headers: Array<Header>,
            responseBody: ByteArray,
            error: Throwable
        ) {
           progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val errorMessage = when (statusCode) {
                401 -> "$statusCode : Bad Request"
                403 -> "$statusCode : Forbidden"
                404 -> "$statusCode : Not Found"
                else -> "$statusCode : ${error.message + " GIT"}"
            }
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    })
}

private fun showRecyclerList() {
    recycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val listDataAdapter =
        UsersAdapter(userFilterList)
    recycleView.adapter = adapter

    listDataAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : UsersAdapter.OnItemClickCallback {
        override fun onItemClicked(dataUsers: DataUsers) {
            showSelectedData(dataUsers)
        }
    })
}

private fun showSelectedData(dataUsers: DataUsers) {
    val dataUser = DataUsers(
        dataUsers.username,
        dataUsers.name,
        dataUsers.avatar,
        dataUsers.company,
        dataUsers.location,
        dataUsers.repository,
        dataUsers.followers,
        dataUsers.following
    )
    val intentDetail = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intentDetail.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DATA, dataUser)
    startActivity(intentDetail)
}
```

}

class UsersAdapter(private var listData: ArrayList) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserHolder>(), Filterable {

```
var userFilterList = ArrayList<DataUsers>()
private lateinit var mcontext: Context


init {
    userFilterList = listData
}

inner class UserHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var imageAvatar: CircleImageView = itemView.avatar
    var name: TextView = itemView.user_name
    var company: TextView = itemView.company
}

private lateinit var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback

fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) {
    this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
}

interface OnItemClickCallback {
    fun onItemClicked(dataUsers: DataUsers)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): UserHolder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_row_users, viewGroup, false)
    val sch = UserHolder(view)
    mcontext = viewGroup.context
    return sch
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userFilterList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserHolder, position: Int) {
    val data = userFilterList[position]
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
        .load(data.avatar)
        .apply(RequestOptions().override(250, 250))
        .into(holder.imageAvatar)
    holder.name.text = data.name
    holder.company.text = data.company
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val dataUser = DataUsers(
            data.username,
            data.name,
            data.avatar,
            data.company,
            data.location,
            data.repository,
            data.followers,
            data.following
        )
        val intentDetail = Intent(mcontext, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intentDetail.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DATA, dataUser)
        mcontext.startActivity(intentDetail)
    }
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            val charSearch = constraint.toString()
            userFilterList = if (charSearch.isEmpty()) {
                listData
            } else {
                val resultList = ArrayList<DataUsers>()
                for (row in userFilterList) {
                    if ((row.username.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                            .contains(charSearch.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)))
                    ) {
                        resultList.add(
                            DataUsers(
                                row.username,
                                row.name,
                                row.avatar,
                                row.company,
                                row.location,
                                row.repository,
                                row.followers,
                                row.following
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
                resultList
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = userFilterList
            return filterResults
        }

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
            userFilterList = results.values as ArrayList<DataUsers>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the usage of **LiveData** and **Kotlin Coroutines** we can avoid callbacks and have a really simple way to present our data to our views.

You should use the Jetpack recommended architecture of MVVM with Repository as DataSource. The flow of Project will be:

You will have your json response via **Retrofit** in Repository as LiveData. From repository it will be recieved by ViewModel as LiveData and View will always be observing the Live Data and will update UI accordingly.